# Range or Domain of Primitive Recursive Function?

Tags: logic, computability

We are given that $A$ is R.E set. I think all of the following are equivalent to that:

> (1) A is the range of one primitive recursive function,
>    (2) A is the domain of one strictly increasing recursive function,
>    (3) A is the range of one strictly increasing recursive function, and
>    (4) $\{ x \in A | x=2k \}$ is a R.E set.

My problem is: we say (set) $A$ is recursive iff $|A|$ is finite or is the range of one strictly increasing recursive function. Why does my TA says the third sentence is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG we might assume $A$ is not finite and $0\in A$.

We take the definition of r.e. sets to be a set is r.e. if its characteristic function is partial recursive.

> Then A set is r.e. iff A is a domain of a strictly increasing partial
>   recursive function.

Proof: (only if) $A=\Phi_e$, define the strictly increasing partial recursive function $f(n)=n, if \Phi_e(n)\downarrow=1$, otherwise undefined.
(if) The characteristic function for A would just be $\chi_A(n)=1$ if $f(n)\downarrow$, which is partial recursive.

> $A$ is $r.e.$ iff $A$ is the range of a primitive recursive function
>   (i.e. (1)).

Proof:

(if) Suppose $A=range(f)$ where $f$ is primitive recursive, then $y\in A \Leftrightarrow\exists n f(n)=y$ so $A$ is r.e. (Only if) If $A$ is r.e., let $e$ be the index of partial recursive function that computes $A$, i.e. $A=\Phi_e$. Then A would be the range of the following primitive recursive function: $f: \omega\times \omega \to \omega$ such that $f(n,s)=n, if \ \Phi_{e,s}(n)\downarrow=1; 0, otherwise$.

It is not clear what you mean by the domain of a recursive function, as normally recursive functions are assumed to be total. So I think you mean partial recursive functions. Being domain of a partial recursive function does give you equivalent characterisation of r.e sets. However, (3) is wrong since it says that $A$ is recursive (range of an increasing total recursive function). Halting set ($\{e: \varphi_e(e)\downarrow\}$) is a non-recursive r.e. set.

Added: **A is r.e. $\Leftrightarrow$ (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2);
A is recursive $\Leftrightarrow$ (3).**
I don't understand the $>x=2k$ part in (4), but you can infer from here.

Well (4) is a strict consequence of r.e
(1) (2) are equivalent to r.e
Under the assumption of r.e They are equivalent for trivial reasons.

Comment: I want to approve, but please clarify your answer with specific part. for example (1) is true, because .... (2) is true because...

Comment: I've edited. There are parts in your question which are not clear, like (4)

Comment: I edited and remove typo in (4), please complete it about (4) to set bounty and approve.

Comment: Multiply everything by 2 produces a function whose range is a subset of even numbers

Comment: Please correct your answer to approve and set bounty, thanks.

Comment: What is k in (4)?

Comment: I think k is a constant, I'm sure there is no meaning for Halting set, am I right

Comment: There is no meaning if k is a constant either, as in this case the set is either singleton or empty.

Comment: Which one can be suppose for k to  this statement be true?

Comment: I have no idea. It's not true at t

Comment: At all that A must be a subset of even numbers. Or even the projection of A onto even numbers being r.e says nothing about A

Comment: we know A is r.e in the question.

Comment: Then it would be equivalent to (1) (2) in the vacuous way.

Comment: $k \in \mathbb{N} $ ?

Comment: yeah, I'm sure it means some x from A that is even, now it's r.e?

Comment: Well it still does not make sense to me. The assertion that some x from A is even is r.e provided that A is r.e. But even when A is r.e this is not necessarily true. Like A=the set of odd numbers.

Comment: I'll suggest you look into the problems/definitions more carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22187/discussion-between-maryam-ghizhi-and-jing-zhang).

Comment: please continue in chat...